# Working with debugger/ terminal view in Sublime Text (Python) gives incorrect indentation errors

Tags: python, terminal

I'm using the TerminalView and SendCode packages in order to be able to debug and request information about datatypes in my code without having to run it in its entirety. However, I keep getting **incorrect** indentation errors. I think it might have to do with the space/ indentation settings, but I cant figure it out.

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m40UZ.png)

Comment: Check if you're mixing tabs and spaces. If this is the case, then convert all tabs to spaces. For more info, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979224/indentation-error-in-python#14979254) thread.

Comment: post your codes, that shall help.

Comment: Hey Vasilis, the settings for my indentation are currently: indentation using space, tab width = 4, and i checked that this is true for all the previous code too, unfortunately it still gives the same error: 'IndentationError: unexpected indent '.

Comment: Hello Aditya, I tried to insert an image as an example of code where it the problem occurs, unfortunately, i cant share all the code, but the problem arises whenever a tab is used, regardless of what the code actually states..

Answer (score 0):

try this(in ST3),select one program page and clik: view-->Indentation-->Convert Indentation to tabs