# Indentation with Python

Tags: python, indentation

I don't understand why i'm getting an indentation error with that type of code. My function is inside a class and the indentation is "normal".

```
def SelectBarriere(self, NumShaker, B_Bar1, B_Bar2, B_Bar3):
    self.Lab_IMV = Label(self, "Configuration IMV:")
    self.Lab_IMV.move(1000, 250)
    self.BarIMVacc = BarPourcentage(self)
    self.BarIMVacc.move(1000,290)
    PoidBarriere1 = self.shakers[NumShaker, 14]
    PoidBarriere2 = self.shakers[NumShaker, 15]
    PoidBarriere3 = self.shakers[NumShaker, 16]
    if B_Bar1 == 2:
        self.MasseThermique = PoidBarriere1
    elif B_Bar2 == 2:
        self.MasseThermique = PoidBarriere2
    elif B_Bar3 == 2:
        self.MasseThermique = PoidBarriere3
    else:
        self.MasseThermique = 0
    return self.MasseThermique
```

The error come at this precise line.

```
PoidBarriere1 = self.shakers[NumShaker, 14]
```

Comment: Can you post the `exception` that you are facing?

Comment: copy paste the code that you wrote here. replace/override the older code. The function written here seems to get defined just fine.

Comment: Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979224/indentation-error-in-python

Comment: what text editor are you using ? You should use 4 spaces instead of tabs. You can convert all tabs to spaces.

Comment: I'm using SublimeText and i copied-past and doesn't work

Comment: It's possible that tabs and spaces got mixed up in your code. Which could happen when copying code for example. Depending on the editor you're using you can convert your tabs to spaces automatically.

Comment: Looking at the sourse of your question, you are mixing tabs and spaces. The line `PoidBarriere1 = ...` has 4 spaces, then 1 tab. The lines before that have 8 spaces. (including the spaces to indent the code block)

Comment: Thank you tobias_k that was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python expects indentation to be consistent, tabs and spaces may be treated differently.

If you have copied some code the spacing may be different. Try the settings in your editor and enable the 'convert tabs to spaces' feature  this will remove ambiguity between tabs and spaces by replacing tabs with a number of spaces.

Comment: Yes tabs and 4 spaces isn't making any difference (in the other parts of my code, i used both and its working). If i delete lines 2 to 5, it's working (I added that part after so maybe there is a problem but.. Where and why)

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine to me. Maybe there is a tab instead of spaces?

Comment: I checked and no only 4 spaces everywhere