# Error pops up about indented block. Need help to stop this error

Tags: python

```
answer = int(raw_input("How many hours a day do you play computer games? ")) 
if answer < 2: 
print "That seems a fairly healthy balance. Well done!" 
elif: 
print "You’re probably good enough by now with all that practice."
print "PS5 are better than any game console"
```

Errors keep popping up that says "There's an error in your program: expected an indented block"

Comment: I recommend you switch to Python 3, Python 2 is not supported anymore.

Comment: Hit a tab or 4 spaces before the print statemets, that's going to make the code work.

Comment: (or however many is one indentation level in your settings, 4 is typical)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp `Where in other programming languages the indentation in code is for readability only, the indentation in Python is very important.`

Comment: Python is based on indentations. The statements you want to be part of the `if` should be indented one level inside it

Comment: This is also useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979224/indentation-error-in-python

Comment: @zabop got another error with the ":" next to the elif

Comment: @AhmedKassim, do you run the same code as shown in an answer to this post?

Comment: @zabop got another error with the " : " next to the elif. i did run it

Comment: `elif` needs to have a condition. Looks like you meant to use `else`

Comment: @AhmedKassim I updated the answer with code that uses `else` in place of the `elif`.

Answer (score 1):

When you code in `python` you ***have*** to indent the code otherwise you'll get the errors like you got. Other programming languages use `;` such as `php` or `java` in order to differentiate the lines to execute, but in `python` we have the indentations. Besides, you can't use `elif` statement without some condition and if you don't have it you have to use `else` instead.

```
answer = int(raw_input("How many hours a day do you play computer games? ")) 

if answer < 2: 
  print "That seems a fairly healthy balance. Well done!" 

else: # instead of elif, which requires a condition
  print "You’re probably good enough by now with all that practice."
  print "PS5 are better than any game console"
```