# IndentationError from downloaded example code

Tags: python, embedded, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

For a Raspberry Pi Pico using Thonny IDE and MicroPython I [downloaded code](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/getting-started-with-the-pico/6):

```
from machine import Pin
import time
led = Pin(15, Pin.OUT)
button = Pin(14, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)
while True:
if button.value():
    led.toggle()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 10
IndentationError: unindent doesn't match any outer indent level
```

Comment: I wonder if you're mixing spaces and tabs. You should be using 4 spaces consistently. See here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979224/indentation-error-in-python

Comment: Your error message mentions line 10 but you only have 8 lines shown above

Comment: I think you should indent after the while statement. PS - Thonny usually detects tabs and suggests you to change them to 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to indent your code properly:

```py
from machine import Pin
import time
led = Pin(15, Pin.OUT)
button = Pin(14, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)
while True:
    if button.value():
        led.toggle()
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
from machine import Pin
import time
led = Pin(15, Pin.OUT)
button = Pin(14, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)
while True:
    if button.value():
        led.toggle()
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

I just changed if button.value(): four more spaces in so its inside the while true: loop.

Comment: wrong: no indentation after ``if`` sentence and unnecessary indentation for first tatement